# Is concurrent collection's contain-like method useless?

Tags: java, concurrency

```
if(concurrentHashMap.containKey(key))
{
    // oops, v has been removed in another thread right after current thread 
    // complete containKey calling
    Value v = concurrentHashMap.get(key); 
    // do something on v                  // null pointer exception
}
```

It seems concurrent collection's contain-like method is useless, to fix above problem:

```
Vaule v = concurrentHashMap.get(key);
if(v != null)
{
    // ok, hold v's reference
    // do something on v
}
```

Am I right?

Comment: firstly you do definitely **NOT** need to do a *get* everytime you do a *containsKey* (it's "containsKey" btw, not "containKey").  So that reason alone make the method *containsKey* not useless at all.  Secondly, *putIfAbsent* could be what you're after: it's the equivalent of a *containsKey* followed by either a *put* or a *get*, but performed atomically.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without specific context. If the problem you're trying to solve is whether the map contains the key when you call containsKey(), then containsKey() works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comment thread: no, `containsKey` does not keep the entry locked in any way, so a later call to `get(key)` might return `null`.  That said, if you're only interested in the boolean -- is the key in the map? -- and you don't need to get the key later on, then `containsKey` is fine.

Additionally, `containsKey` is required by the `Map` interface, so it's not like it wouldn't be there anyway.

Comment: Don't forget the case where access is known to be synchronized. When the race can't exist (e.g. single-threaded use) there is no reason to incur any higher cost than a lock-less check in ContainsKey

Answer (score 5):

It's not useless. Imagine the case where nothing needs to be done with the result of `get`. In this case, both `containsKey` and `get` have (and suffer from) the same issues.

As Voo points out in a comment, however, code can often be written in terms of [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29) (which is designed to represent a larger atomic operation).

It just *does not* (as it cannot by itself) create a larger *atomic context*. That is, there is *nothing* preventing other threads from doing stuff to `concurrentHashMap` between `containsKey` and `get`. Pay close attention to the [contract from the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> ...even though all *[individual]* operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and *there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access*...
>
> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). **Retrievals [e.g. containsKey or get] reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations** holding upon their onset...

There is a difference between an object being "thread-safe" and correctly using said object in a concurrent context.

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 - multi-threaded programming with shared data structures always requires careful thought ... and more than surface understanding of how the chosen data structure classes actually work.  Read the javadoc carefully.

Comment: Actually the only reason I'd ever use `containsKey` instead of `contains` is exactly the one scenario where it is NOT equivalent to `get(x) != null` - but then I've yet to see a scenario where storing null values in a map was such a splendid idea to begin with (and we can easily fix it with some kind of null object pattern), so we probably can ignore that. Also most of the time we want `putIfAbsent` anyhow which avoids the problem nicely and offers useful atomicity guarantees.