# Not thread safe methods of CuncurrentSkipListMap in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, treemap

In my Java project I need to use TreeMap in multihreaded way. I found that ConcurrentSkipListMap is what that I need but some methods are not thread safe. One of them - containsKey(Object key). What is a typical solution for using this methods in multhreded way? In my program I need put key that will not replace old and if it's impossible I will be putting another key while will not get unique key. What construction should use instead containsKey as i can't lost information?

Comment: What do you mean, `containsKey` isn't thread safe?

Comment: I read in documentation that this method is not thread safe.

Comment: What gives you the impression `containsKey` isn't thread safe?

Comment: @ChrisK How is it not thread-safe at all?  What do you define as thread-safe?

Comment: Its from documentation: "Additionally, the bulk operations putAll, equals, toArray, containsValue, and clear are not guaranteed to be performed atomically. For example, an iterator operating concurrently with a putAll operation might view only some of the added elements."

Comment: @ChrisK "*Insertion, removal, update, and access operations safely execute concurrently by multiple threads*" - [ConcurrentSkipListMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) documentation

Comment: @alex.seluta Yes, that is absolutely true, but it doesn't imply it isn't thread-safe it implies the methods aren't atomic.

Comment: Alex, I will try to illustrate what non-atomic means, imagine the following: map.keySet().toArray() - you'd expect to have a snapshot of the map itself by the time toArray() was called, right? Actually the snapshot you may get can be interfered from any threads and may never actually represent the state of the keySet(). Still it's tread-safe and any mutations are guaranteed not to cause any broken invariants. In that aspect containsKey is perfectly thread safe. It's another story if CSLM would the right tool for the job.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9058524/2073130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are worried about containsKey results going stale before you can act on them, or about [this warning in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html):

> Additionally, the bulk operations putAll, equals, toArray, containsValue, and clear are not guaranteed to be performed atomically. For example, an iterator operating concurrently with a putAll operation might view only some of the added elements.

there are methods defined on ConcurrentSkipListMap that you can use instead. For instance, see  [putIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, associate it with the given value. This is equivalent to

```
if (!map.containsKey(key))
    return map.put(key, value);
else
    return map.get(key);
```

> except that the action is performed atomically.

Also see the methods remove and replace.

Comment: In my programm I need put key that will not replace old and if it's impossible I will be putting another key while will not get unique key. What construction should use instead containsKey? As i can't lost information.

Comment: `putIfAbsent` ought to take care of that, I think?  If you want to put something into the map but not overwrite something that got into the map in the meantime.